# dnSpy: What do included reference assemblies affect?

Tags: dll, dnspy

I'm modifying a DLL through dnSpy, and said modification required a reference assembly in order to recompile. The modification did not necessitate the reference assembly, it was just needed in order to recompile the changed section, with or without the change.

So, my question is this: Does the reference assembly chosen modify the recompiled DLL? For example, if I had two different versions of the reference assembly, one which the DLL was originally compiled with and meant to use, and the other a different version I used during recompilation using dnSpy, which reference assembly would the recompiled DLL use?